# Custom WordPress post types NO PLUGIN

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

So I been tasked with creating two custom post types for WordPress as an exercise. Was wondering what direction I should go with this. Check it out below:

Part 1

- Create a custom post type called Products
- A Product needs fields in the admin for Title, Link, Image, Background-color
- Take each of the images from the product-images directory, and create a product from them.
- Each one should have:

  - a different background-color
  - a different title
- Display these Products on the home page, and make sure that it looks good in every screen size. You can refer to the screenshot called products, in the screenshots directory, to see how it should look.

Part 2

Create a custom post type called videos

- A video only needs fields in the admin for Name, youtube-id
- Take each of the videos listed in the text file videos-list and create a video from them.
- On the home page, below the products section, create a new section and that shows only one video and a list of text links for the other videos. Refer to the screenshot called videos, also in the screenshots directory to see how it should look.
- When you click the link to another video in the list, the video displaying on the home page should change and become the new video

Can anyone give me some direction on how to go about this. I understand how to create a custom post type. What I don't seem to get is how to create fields for a bg color and image. For the video section I am further confused as to how to actually create the section with links on the right and a video that changes to the left once the appropriate link has been clicked.

I'm not a WordPress guru by any means so any help on these 2 problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't use plugins for this exercise unfortunately.

Comment: Read the docs then: https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Comment: Please check this https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/